# Assigning external style sheet page to razor page in .core web application

Tags: asp.net-core

As you all know, in all normal .net framework empty web site projects every asp page has a head section in which we specify the external style sheet of that asp page. But I am shifting to .core web application project where pages do not have a head section. There is a head section in shared _layout but I do not want to use it because, as far as I know, the link for style sheet is shared across all pages what I shall do.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement of adding references to external stylesheets inside the `<head>` section of page from view page(s), you can try following approach.

In `_Layout.cshtml`,   calling `RenderSection` to optionally reference `Styles` section in the  section, like below.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
</head>
```

Then you can add reference to the external style sheet file like below in view page.

```
@section Styles{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/mystyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: thank u  for answer i am going to work only at my view page i will set 
@{
 Layout = "";
} so my page dont take _style from layout  then i will apply your @section style code

Comment: 1) My above solution could help add references to external stylesheets inside the `<head>` section; 2) Your approach of adding external stylesheet references, which would be added to <body> part.

Answer (score 0):

till now the easiest solution i found
(1)- prevent your page from taking style from default shared (_layout.)
by writing the following code at your page

(2)- your razor page like any other html page can accept head section tag 
and can accept  tag even if it is not placed in head section
so refer to your external style sheet as u normally do
write following link tag at your razor page without head section

```
(1)
@{
Layout = "";}



<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" />
```